Image contained in parent element using tailwind flexbox layout
I have a template layout using flexbox and tailwindcss.  I am trying to superimpose svg onto an an image and confine them to the max size of parent container.  The image and SVG need to be responsive.  Tried for hours/days different methods.   Overall size of the page needs to be 80vv and changes with resizing.
Change vh to different element, tried giving same attributes to svg and image
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex h-dvh flex-col bg-black">
  <div class="flex items-baseline justify-between bg-red-400 px-2 py-1">
    <div>MRI Brain</div>
    <button type="button" class="bg-white">
      <div class="p-1">Learn</div>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="flex flex-grow max-h-100 bg-blue-400">
    <div class="bg-orange-400">reformats</div>
    <div class="flex flex-grow flex-col bg-pink-400">
      <div class="flex justify-center bg-red-800">sequences</div>

      <div class="relative flex flex-grow items-center justify-center bg-teal-400">
        <img class="object-contain flex-grow" src="https://radiologytemplates.co.uk/storage/images/processed/2_1716024497_189_CTNeck_Coronal_SoftTissue.jpg" />
        <svg class="absolute border-2 border-red-400" object-contain viewBox="0 0 550 550">
          <path style="opacity:0.28;fill:#00BFA5;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.5" d="m 177.54135,133.59116 3.04605,-14.35996 4.78666,-6.52725 6.0921,-7.39756 -3.4812,-12.619362 -15.66541,-8.703007 -10.00846,3.046053 -6.09211,14.359966 1.7406,20.01691 5.88547,25.98157 0.20664,23.62557 -0.64179,14.79512 -0.12745,15.96858 3.83716,9.78448 6.07024,2.96686 3.04605,-2.17575 v -6.52726 c 0,0 -3.04605,-4.3515 -3.04605,-8.26785 0,-3.91636 0.8703,-16.10057 0.8703,-16.10057 l -0.8703,-5.2218 v -6.96241 l 0.8703,-13.05451 1.7406,-16.97086 z" id="path844" pid="53" />
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center bg-red-100">opacity</div>
    </div>

    <div class="bg-purple-400">structures</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-yellow-400">footer</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>


Your HTML is invalid. A <div> is not allowed within a <button> element.

You can use the image inside the svg element with . Do not forget to use href instead of src

Currently using image inside svg, but trying to preload images without preloading svg as having performance issues with preloading interactive svgs if that makes sense.

Eventually I found a way to keep images of the same aspect ratio within the viewport, regardless of container size. The basic idea is:

Use relative-absolute layout so that the parent element controls the width and height of the child elements.
use object-fit to make sure the image don't overflow.

But <img> tag can't have child elements, we can't layout relative to the image, nor can we get the real image size after object-fit.
But if two images have the same aspect ratio, we just need to align their scaling behavior separately.
It is also possible to control the scaling behavior of svg elements, but not through the object-fit CSS property, but through the preserveAspectRatio attribute. By default, preserveAspectRatio has a value of xMidYMid meet, which behaves like object-fit: contain, so nothing needs to be specified here.
So just change your code to the following:
<!-- .... -->
<div class="flex justify-center bg-red-800">sequences</div>
<!-- ========== ↓ relevant ↓ ========== -->
<div class="relative grow">
  <img class="absolute h-full w-full object-contain" src="https://radiologytemplates.co.uk/storage/images/processed/2_1716024497_189_CTNeck_Coronal_SoftTissue.jpg" />
  <svg class="absolute h-full w-full border-2 border-red-400" viewBox="0 0 550 550">
    <path style="opacity:0.28;fill:#00BFA5;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.5" d="m 177.54135,133.59116 3.04605,-14.35996 4.78666,-6.52725 6.0921,-7.39756 -3.4812,-12.619362 -15.66541,-8.703007 -10.00846,3.046053 -6.09211,14.359966 1.7406,20.01691 5.88547,25.98157 0.20664,23.62557 -0.64179,14.79512 -0.12745,15.96858 3.83716,9.78448 6.07024,2.96686 3.04605,-2.17575 v -6.52726 c 0,0 -3.04605,-4.3515 -3.04605,-8.26785 0,-3.91636 0.8703,-16.10057 0.8703,-16.10057 l -0.8703,-5.2218 v -6.96241 l 0.8703,-13.05451 1.7406,-16.97086 z" id="path844" pid="53" />
  </svg>
</div>
<!-- ========== ↑ relevant ↑ ========== -->
<div class="flex justify-center bg-red-100">opacity</div>
<!-- .... -->

Demo on Tailwind Play.

Amazing cheers works as expected.  Now back to remainder of the layout.
